# Error in factor(newCases[, a], levels = 1:nlevels(data[, a]), labels = levels(data[, : invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2

Tags: r, smote

I am running SMOTE function as given below :

```
# install.packages("DMwR") for SMOTE implementation
```

`library(DMwR)
smoted_data <- SMOTE(state~., deliq, perc.over=200, perc.under = 1600)`

But i am getting below error :

`Error in factor(newCases[, a], levels = 1:nlevels(data[, a]), labels = levels(data[,  : 
invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 2 In addition: Warning message:
In smote.exs(data[minExs, ], ncol(data), perc.over, k) :
NAs introduced by coercion`

I checked all factor variables and none of them contains 0 at any level.

No NA's are available in the data as well, i checked all related posts in stackoverflow but did not get anything relevant to my case.

What are possible reasons for this?

Comment: Is it possible to `dput(deliq)` and add it to your question? It could be a data issue.

Comment: I tried the function but the output of dput() is very large(even not remained in console).

Comment: How about `dput(head(deliq))`?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found was to do something like the following (keep only the predictors and the target variable).

```
x <- your independent variables

  fmla <- as.formula(paste("state ~ ", paste(x, collapse= "+")))

smoted_data <- SMOTE(fmla, subset(deliq, select = c("state",x)), perc.over=200,perc.under = 1600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that those factor(s) variable are truly in factor format and not character(s).
Do this to check:
str(mydata)
If any of them are in character, put them back in factor format using this:
as.factor(myvariable)